# SQL Server 2014 Management Studio won't remember custom color

Tags: sql-server, ssms

This is the SSMS version I'm using:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 12.0.4100.1
```

In previous versions (2008R2) I was able to set a custom color for my production and UAT server and SSMS remembered my settings. In the newer version (above) my "Use custom color" setting doesn't remember for each server independently. The color is always the last one that I chose no matter which server I connect to.

- Connect to Server
- Server name: xyz
- Options >>
- Connection properties tab
- Use custom color: Select...

Is there a fix for this or perhaps it has something to do with my local installation of SSMS?

Comment: Hi @Uporabnik003, may be your question belongs to the dba stack ...  Anyway, good question :)

Comment: Hmmm.... I have SSMS 12.0.4213.0 (SQL Server 2014 SP1), and from what I can see, it works just fine. I have set up several servers in "Registered Servers" list, and each has a separate custom color, and those are in fact applied

Comment: @Uporabnik003, very useful tip. Thank you

Comment: @marc_s I never used Registered servers before. But it is working if I do it that way. Please post you comment as an answer (must be using Registered servers) and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmmm.... I have SSMS 12.0.4213.0 (SQL Server 2014 SP1), and from what I can see, it works just fine.

I have set up several servers in my `Registered Servers` list in SSMS, and each has a separate custom color, and those colors are in fact applied.

**Update (05-Oct-2017)**

Those colors are *only* applied to the query window inside SSMS if you

- go to the `Registered Servers` window inside SSMS
- select your target server you want to connect to
- right-click and select either `Object Explorer` (to open that server in OE), or `New Query` to open a new query window for that server

If you just pick the `Connect` button inside Object Explorer and type in your server name, then those colors apparently are *not applied* ... (not sure if it's a bug - or a feature)

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2012 (v17.2).  I've added the Custom Colors to the Registered Servers screen.... but it fails miserably.  I connect to those servers, and no colors get added.

Comment: @MikeGledhill: the colors are defined in the "Registered Servers" view, and will *only* be applied if you connect to that particular server from within that view (in "Registered Servers", click on the server you want, right-click and pick "Object Explorer" or "New Query"); if you connect separately (by using the "Connect" dialog in the "Object Explorer", then the colors do not get applied, that is correct (annoying, too - but that's the way it is, for now)

Comment: Hi Marc - thanks.  I didn't realise that.  As you said... damn, that's annoying, and really user-unfriendly.  I might just stick with the Redgate Tools to do the tab coloring, in that case.  Merci b'coup, and danke schön !

Comment: This seems to be fixed now.  I've setup a registered server with a custom color.  When I log in thru a link on my desktop then the color kicks in.  I'm on SSMS 14.0.17230